# Java - How to make an ArrayList access a different class method?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

I'm a beginner in Java and I struggle a bit. I have 3 classes and I want the ArrayList from one class to access a method from another class. How can I do that?

Here is the method I want to retrieve the method from:

```
  private void markAsUpdated()
  {
    this.needsUpdate = true;
  }
```

Here is the arrayList:

```
public int getNumberOfUpdatedSites()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < webSite.size(); i++)
    {
      if (webSite.get(i))
      {

      }
    }
```

Both code belong to two different classes.
I'm stuck at the iteration part.
Basically it needs to return all the sites that are already updated. I have a UML diagram if needed I can provide it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `webSite`? Given how you use a value from it as the condition in an `if` statement, I guess it must be `List<Boolean>`? What is it you want to do with `markAsUpdated()`, which is a method, not a class?

Comment: actually it is ArrayList<Website> websites;  Where <Website> is the class from which I get the markAsUpdated() method

Comment: markAsUpdated() is responsible to set a boolean variable to false

Comment: This variable will be responsible for telling if a website needs an update or not

Comment: The method should be visible to other classes, use the access modifier `public` instead of `private`, also essentially what you are doing is marking all elements, so the `if` statement don't make much sense here.

Comment: Oh I see now, I was stoned when I started working on it so that's why I made it a private. My bad. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you need to check whether a website has been updated you should have a (public) method in the `Website` class which returns the value of the instance variable `needsUpdate`. Also, if I understand correctly, `markAsUpdated` should set the `needsUpdate` variable to false.

Comment: Yep I have a public boolean method which returns the value of needsUpdate. Thanks for telling me to change needsUpdate to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Website` class is as follows:

```java
public class Website {
    private boolean needsUpdate;

    public boolean isNeedsUpdate() {
        return needsUpdate;
    }

    public void markAsUpdated() {
        this.needsUpdate = false;
    }
}
```

Then in your other class, you just need to call the public `isNeedsUpdate` method to check if it needs to be updated or not. This means that in your other class you can do as follows:

```java
public int getNumberOfUpdatedSites() {
    int updatedWebsitesCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < webSite.size(); i++) {
        if (!webSite.get(i).isNeedsUpdate()){
            updatedWebsitesCount++;
        }
    }

    return updatedWebsitesCount;
}
```